# ASP.NET (VB.NET 4.5) Calling Async WCF Method

Tags: vb.net, wcf, asynchronous, .net-4.5

I have been reading for days, and I can't quite figure out what I am supposed to do here.  I am actually a C# developer and programming in VB.NET can be a little confusing at times.  That aside, I am trying to implement Async calls from a WCF in a new project that I am creating here.  I've tried it a few different ways with results, but I want to make sure what I am doing is proper.

From what I have read, you should never return a void in an async method, so I am trying my hardest to avoid it.  All of that aside, I guess I just want to know if this is a valid way to go about building this page.  It will be calling more than one method from the WCF as I build it out.

```
Public Class _DefaultReservation
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim wcfReservation As WCFReservation.WDReservationClient

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    SetupPage()

End Sub


Private Async Sub SetupPage()

    wcfReservation = DirectCast(Master, LoggedInMaster).wcfReservation

    Dim resData As String = Await wcfReservation.GetDataAsync(123)
    Response.Write(resData)

End Sub

End Class
```

I guess what is confusing is if I put that code inside of an async function and return the task, I would have to mark the page_load handler as async as well.  It doesn't seem right doing it this way?  By doing that it seems like an async function is calling an async function.  But the way I am doing it here, my async function returns void, and that is supposed to be avoided.  I can post an example of the other way too if needed.  Thank you!!

Edit: Does this work better?

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
```

Public Class _DefaultReservation
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Dim wcfReservation As WCFReservation.WDReservationClient

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    SetupPage()

End Sub


Private Async Sub SetupPage()

    wcfReservation = DirectCast(Master, LoggedInMaster).wcfReservation

    Dim getDataResult = Await GetDataAsync()
    Response.Write(getDataResult)

End Sub

Private Function GetDataAsync() As Task(Of String)

    Return wcfReservation.GetDataAsync(123)

End Function
```

End Class

EDIT 3:

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
```

Public Class _DefaultReservation
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Dim wcfReservation As WCFReservation.WDReservationClient

Protected Async Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    wcfReservation = DirectCast(Master, LoggedInMaster).wcfReservation

    Dim result As String = Await wcfReservation.GetDataAsync(1234)
    Response.Write(result)

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true you should avoid `async void`. The exception for this guideline is when you have `async` event handlers.

Such as `Page_Load`.

For more information about this guideline, see my MSDN article on [Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

> It doesn't seem right doing it this way? By doing that it seems like an async function is calling an async function.

That's perfectly correct. Async code will "grow" through your code base. The correct solution is to make `SetupPage` a `Task`-returning function and `await` it in `Page_Load` (which is an `async void`/Sub).

**Edit:**

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Public Class _DefaultReservation Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

  Dim wcfReservation As WCFReservation.WDReservationClient

  Protected Async Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim getDataResult = Await GetDataAsync()
    Response.Write(getDataResult)
  End Sub

  Public Function GetDataAsync() As Task(Of String)
    wcfReservation = DirectCast(Master, LoggedInMaster).wcfReservation
    Return wcfReservation.GetDataAsync(123)
  End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you Stephen.  I am having two issues, the first that I want to simplify my solution to death.  The other being breaking the page into logical blocks, I think I can do it if I change Page_Load to async, but I will lose how I can organize my code.  I've edited my post, maybe it works better now?

Comment: "I will lose how I can organize my code" doesn't make any sense to me. I reviewed your new code, but stand by my recommendation to only use `async void` in event handlers; `SetupPage` should be an `async Task` function.

Comment: I am overthinking this, for sure.  Maybe I need to get back to the basics here... Edit 3, is what I *believe* you are saying?

Comment: I've added an edit with some code, though my VB is quite rusty. The idea is to have `Async Sub` only used for event handlers, and also attempt to move any context-sensitive portions (e.g., `Response`) as close to those handlers as possible. This makes your utility methods (e.g., `GetDataAsync`) easier to unit test.

Comment: That makes perfect sense to me, thank you again!  I miss events already!

Answer (score 1):

As luck would have it, I just [posted about Async Sub](http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/Beware-of-Async-Sub-or-Void) yesterday. Long story short, in your case if you use Async Sub, control will revert to the calling method as soon as the await is encountered. As a result, your page_Load handler will end before the SetupPage is complete. If you want to have Page_Load wait until SetupPage has asynchronously completed, you need to change the SetupPage to be a function returning Task and then Await SetupPage in Page_Load (causing Page_Load) to be Async.

Async Sub is valid on event handlers. Lucian discusses this at some length in his recent [Async Patterns post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2013/02/18/talk-the-new-async-design-patterns.aspx). You may also want to check out the [Async talk from ASP.Net Conf](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/aspConf/aspConf/Async-in-ASP-NET) last year for special considerations on using Async with ASP.Net/WCF.